# Is it possible to get the query that is erroring using Entity Core Framework along with the parameter values?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core-2.2, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have a project that is written using C# on the top on ASP.NET Core 2.2 framework. I am using Entity Framework Core to interact with my MySQL server.

I have a console app that executes back end tasks on regular bases and when a job fails, I get an email.

I keep getting the following error

> Error Message: Out of range value for column 'Value' at row 1

However, that isn't telling me what query is throwing the error. My stack trace is pointing me to a `DataContext.AddRange()` call but I can't seem to figure out the value that is causing this problem.

Is it possible to get the full query that is erroring from Entity Framework Core along with the values being inserted or updated?

Comment: Did you check out the article on Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging, I think that should provide you the info you're looking for

Comment: Another option could be to observe incoming queries on MySQL, here is an article that tells you how to do that: https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/10/how-to-show-queries-log-in-mysql.html

Comment: Two things I usually use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore nuget because the Microsoft’s one was giving me problems (not saying this is the cause) other thing have you tried to use DataContext.Add()? Just for the heck of it, yes you have to use a for cycle. Without more context isn’t easy

Comment: This process rarely fails and changing AddRange() to Add() will take extremely longer time to execute in which I have to avoid